# ElasticSearch - Return only unique values in query

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, elk

G'day.

I've been struggling with this one for a while, as I'm new to ElasticSearch and I'd really appreciate some guidance or advice.

My goal is to execute a query that retrieves a list of *unique* IP values, which is filtered by when they last appeared.

What I'm struggling with is the *unique* part. I've done some experimenting with "aggs", which worked to get unique values, but I coulnd't figure out a way to still get the results sorted by when they last appeared.

I've included my query below, my goal is to limit the results so no duplicates of "src_ip" are returned while still sorting by @timestamp, or at least retrieving the last found values.

```
Get _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "type": "CitrixHoneypot|Ciscoasa"
    }
  },
  "_source": ["@timestamp", "src_ip", "type"],
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 500
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requested query would be something like below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "type": "CitrixHoneypot|Ciscoasa"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_ip": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "src_ip",
        "size": 500
      },"aggs": {
        "top_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [{"@timestamp":{ "order": "desc" }}],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },"size": 0
}
```

In this query, first you find the unique `src_ips` then you select the most latest document using top hits and sort over `@timestamp`.